# Stop null warnings for properties during render

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a component that renders it's template with for example a span that looks like:

```
<span>{{item.name}}</span>
```

the item is passed in as a property:

```
props: {
        item: null
    },
```

when the component is first mounted item is null, so when the render happens I get this in the logs:

> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name'
>   of null"

If I create a computed property like this:

```
computed: {
        name() {
            if (this.item != null) {
                return this.item.name
            }
        }
    },
```

And then put name instead of item.name in the render it works fine, but is there a way to tell Vue to stop complaining about subproperties being null since it doesn't seem to care about root properties being null?

Maybe @LinusBorg knows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not Vue-specific. Vue is simply warning you that you have a javascript `TypeError`. The error is being caused because you can't access a property of a `null` value in javascript.

I would just set the default value of your `item` prop to an empty object instead of `null`:

```
props: {
  item: { type: Object, default: () => ({}) }
}
```

Comment: So previously I was initializing the values to null in the parent for example in the data block of the parent it would be:

data: {
item: null
}

So should I just switch this to:

data: {
item: {}
}

Or is there a better way? Thanks!

Comment: If you're referencing a property of `item` in your component's template, I would still set the default value to be an empty object, just as a safeguard.